# iggridupdating - Updating grid cell values as you type

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I'm using Infragistics' igGrid to handle data on my company's web application. We want to use the grid as an "editable grid" for user data interaction (add/edit/delete/view records).

The scenario I want to play out is for when the user inputs a valid item name into a one cell in a new row, the next cell automatically gets populated with the corresponding description of that item. So far I'm unable to make it update automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [the official "Editing Combo Editor" sample](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/editing-combo-editor) will give you the answer you're looking for :)

As noted in its description, changing the "Product Name" column auto-fills the "Price" column.
NB: You will need to select a "Category name" first though

There are 2 steps that you need to implement in order to get the desired outcome:

1. Hook to the igCombo's "Selection Changed" event in the context of the igGrid, since igCombo instances will be children to the igGrid's DOM:

   ```
   $(document).delegate("#grid1", "iggridrendered", function (evt, ui) {
   var updating = $("#grid1").data("igGridUpdating");
   var editor = updating.editorForKey("ProductID");
   if (editor) {
       $(document).delegate("#comboProductID", "igcomboselectionchanged", comboSelectionChanged);
   }
   else {
       var colSettings = updating.options.columnSettings;
       colSettings[2].editorOptions.selectionChanged = comboSelectionChanged;
   }});
   ```
2. Write up an event handler that will update the editor field for the desired column (Price in this case):

   function comboSelectionChanged(evt, ui) {
   var items = ui.items || [];
   if (items.length === 1) {
       var item = items[0];
       var editor = $("#grid1").igGridUpdating("editorForKey", "Price");
       $(editor).igEditor("value", products[item.index].Price);
   }
   }

The steps are taken from the HTML code view of the Sample (just below the grid).
If you want to have a better look at that code view snippet, I've placed it in a stand-alone JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BorislavTraykov/4uJBD/

If the solution doesn't work out for you, please elaborate some more on the scenario you are aiming to accomplish.